# Java BufferedImage loading not working | problems with the path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bufferedreader

I have a method that converts a image to buffered image

```
public static BufferedImage imageLoader(String path)
```

it returns when loading the image..

```
    return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
```

so when i try to load and display the image on my canvas i do this..

```
testImage = ImageLoad.imageLoader("textures/sky.png");
```

ok so what im getting at is the fact that this doesn't load correctly and im trying to figure out why, when i load it here's what happens...

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    input==null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at gfx.ImageManager.ImageLoad.imageLoader(ImageLoad.java:14)
    at game.Thread.GameThread.init(GameThread.java:119)
    at game.Thread.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:30)
    at game.Thread.GameThread.startThread(GameThread.java:50)
    at launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:15)
```

so basically it didn't load correctly, the reason im putting all this information is because I've asked several people and they couldn't figure it out. So i'm looking to see if I did something wrong, or if there's an easier solution. Here's my project's src folder...

I am using IntelliJ if that helps.

Comment: Where is the image stored? Could you provide the function that gives you problems instead of loose lines?

Comment: Its stored in a separate package but its still in the same root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet from the implementation of [`ImageIO.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File))

```
* @exception IllegalArgumentException if <code>input</code> is
* <code>null</code>.
* @exception IOException if an error occurs during reading.
*/
public static BufferedImage read(File input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
    }
```

which should confirm that the value that you are passing to the method is `null` and help you debug why possibly `ImageLoader.class.getResource(path)` could/would be `null` for your shared code above.

Since it's dependent on few other variables like `path` and `ImageLoader`'s definition, I would leave it on you to do some debugging there and sort it out.

Comment: Suggest him to place image in the project root and read it as `File` with `ImageIO.read(File input)`. Reading resource files can be tricky for  newbies.

Comment: Im going to try that guy with a name i cant type

Comment: @КлаусШварц That is where I left it as *I would leave it on you to do some debugging there and sort it out.*

Comment: I figured it out, it appears to have been something wrong with the image i was trying to display.